# gdb 6.8 and 7.0 difference. Missing line numbers for xfs cu

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, xfs

I have elf file with debug info. Using gdb 6.5 - 6.8 I get the following output:
    (gdb) info line xfs_write
    Line 634 of "fs/xfs/linux-2.6/xfs_lrw.c" starts at address 0xc021cfe1
     and ends at 0xc021cfed .


Using gdb 7.0+:


    (gdb) info line xfs_write
    No line number information available for address 0xc021cfe1 


readelf shows line information and DWARF2 version used. What has changed to gdb that could cause that behavior ?